# Remove updates text on plugin or themes list page

Tags: plugins, themes, updates

I seen update messages as like  "**There is a new version of BLAH PLUGIN available on BLAH SITE. View version 3.1.3 details or automatically update**" on plugin list page and themes listing page before install the **Disable WordPress Updates** plugin.

I thought after installed the plugin these lines will be removed. But it was not.

**How can i remove these updates text from plugin list or themes list page?**

Comment: They vanish automagically after the update.

Comment: But i have customized some coding in that plugin. What if my client clicks on the "automatically update" link. All the changes which i done in that plugin will be lost?

Answer (score 1):

Add `define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);` to your `wp-config.php` file.

> This will block users being able to use the plugin and theme
>   installation/update functionality from the WordPress admin area.
>   Setting this constant also disables the Plugin and Theme editor (i.e.
>   you don't need to set DISALLOW_FILE_MODS and DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT, as on
>   it's own DISALLOW_FILE_MODS will have the same effect).
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants

The messages go away as well. I just tested it. Note: This also disable the file editor, which, in my opinion makes it doubleplusgood.